# Azure Web Job Zip deployment Error due to Size

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-webjobs, invoke-restmethod

I am deploying a web job through powershell script and can manage to get the publishing credentials and then add the access token in the authorization header. All is fine until it uploads the zip file when I receive file size error: **The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.**

```
#Function to get Publishing credentials for the WebApp :
        function Get-PublishingProfileCredentials($resourceGroupName, $AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs) {

                $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
                $resourceName = "$AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs/publishingcredentials"
                $publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType `
                        $resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion $Apiversion -Force
                return $publishingCredentials
        }

        #Pulling authorization access token :
        function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs) {

                $publishingCredentials = Get-PublishingProfileCredentials $resourceGroupName $AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs
                return ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f `
                                                        $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
        }


        $accessToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs
        #Generating header to create and publish the Webjob :
        $Header = @{
                'Content-Disposition' = 'attachment; attachment; filename=Copy.zip'
                'Authorization'       = $accessToken
        }
        $apiUrl = "http://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/app_data/jobs/triggered/Test/"
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $Header -Method put `
        -InFile "D:\Work\WebJobs\WebJobsBuild\Test.zip" -ContentType 'application/zip' `
        -TimeoutSec 600
```

[image]

The zip file size is only 43MB. How can I check the upper limit of file size allowed and how can I increase it? I've tried both Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod but the result is the same

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, the response seems to come from Azure AD (login.microsoftonline.com) so i would check the authentication part first.

Comment: After various attempts, I finally found that `$apiUrl` was wrong. I have tested it and posted the modified code at the bottom.

Comment: My webjob release file is `72.4M`, everything is normal, so the problem is not that the file size is limited. Check some blogs that the file limit is about `110M`, and it has not been tested. If you are interested, you can research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I modify `$apiUrl` and it works for me.

It should be like

`$apiUrl = "https://$AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/MyWebJob1"`

Step 1. My test webjob in portal, and I will create `MyWebJob1` later.

[image]

Step 2. Before running cmd.

[image]

Step 3. Modify the web job name as `MyWebJob1`.

[image]

[image]

Step 4. Check the webjob in portal.

[image]

## Sample Code

```
    $resourceGroupName='***';
    $AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs='jas***pp';
    $Apiversion='2019-08-01';

    #Function to get Publishing credentials for the WebApp :
    function Get-PublishingProfileCredentials($resourceGroupName, $AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs) {

            $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
            $resourceName = "$AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs/publishingcredentials"
            $publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType `
                    $resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion $Apiversion -Force
            return $publishingCredentials
    }

    #Pulling authorization access token :
    function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs) {

            $publishingCredentials = Get-PublishingProfileCredentials $resourceGroupName $AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs
            return ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f `
                                                    $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
    }


    $accessToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs
    #Generating header to create and publish the Webjob :
    $Header = @{
            'Content-Disposition' = 'attachment; attachment; filename=test.zip'
            'Authorization'       = $accessToken
    }
    $apiUrl = "https://$AppServiceNameToDeployWebJobs.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/MyWebJob1" 
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $Header -Method put `
    -InFile "E:\test.zip" -ContentType 'application/zip' `
    -TimeoutSec 600
```